# Creating a project structure similar to Spring Petclinic in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

How do I create a project structure in Eclipse similar to `Spring Petclinic` where

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java
```

are all source folders.Is it created using Maven or is it created using simple Java Project ?

Comment: Yes, it is created using maven

Comment: ok . Which maven archetype should I use for that is you can help on that

Comment: I believe the corresponding archetype is the maven-archetype-quickstart one. See http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-bundles/maven-archetype-quickstart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can generate the skeleton of almost any Java project type using [Maven archetypes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html).

Executing the maven command `mvn archetype:generate` specifying an `archetypeArtifactId` parameter will automatically create your project structure. For example, `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart` will execute the command with the *maven-archetype-quickstart* archetype (note that you should also provide your artifactId and your groupId).

You should take a look at [Maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html), it will take you through the creation of such project structure without any troubles and it's a very good introduction if you are new to Maven.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can create the project using **[Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html)**. This **[tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/)** might get you started on how to create Spring web-applications using Maven.

If you are familiar with **[Git](http://git-scm.com/)**, you can also download and import the **[spring-petclinic](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/)** from Github.

[image]